# emacs lsp, how to make each window have a different transition history M-. and M-,?

Tags: emacs, language-server-protocol

When I go to a function or class definition in one window/buffer and then to a completely different definition in another window/buffer, the story they share! That is, if I go back from the function definition in the first buffer, it will open in it the call to the function whose definition I opened in the second buffer! How can I make a local history for each buffer with LSP + Emacs? Without tags and stuff.